# What information hub are you using in your work?

Tags: communication, pm-software, tools, documentation

I have team working over internet. In that case is very important to have a good information hub. The hub can be integrated with the task management system but this isn't required. My team is working in the scrum methodology.

Do you know some free solutions?

Comment: This forum does not give specific product advice, instead focusing on the processes and methods of doing project management.

Answer (score 2):

If the budget is a constraints something as simple as Google site can be used. If you have a gmail account explore http://sites.google.com
It allows you to upload documents, share information on web pages, create posts for periodic activity and a lot more.

Comment: The suggestion is too general. I was working with Google apps in one of the project. The Google apps without additional customization are nothing special. The good thing was common company email but the rest looks very poor. Next important thing is about no support in case of problem from Google for free version. In that case i would like to choose virtual server with my administration and some free tools.